# Clear last rows while statement is true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I loop a function to clear the last row if a statement is true?

Example: 
In the first column I have dates or the string 'BugFix' each in a different  row. I need to clear every 'BugFix' if it is in the last row.

```
Column A
  ------
1  BugFix
2  some Date
3  BugFix
4  some Date
5  BugFix
6  BugFix
```

In this example I would need to clear two rows:  5 and 6

- Clear last row (row 6) because the value is BugFix.
- Check if in new last row (row 5) is BugFix
- It is, so clear that row, check again, but do nothing because in new last row (4) is some Date.

My code only clears row 6. Please help.

```
function clearLogs(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('logs');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  var data = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue(); 

  if (lastRow == 'BugFix') {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).clear();    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is analyze your values from the "bottom up".

This code does it for you:

```
function clearLastBugFixes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowAValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];}); //The Map functions filters the values only to the ones we want (Column A).
  Logger.log(rowAValues);

  var counter = 0;
  while (rowAValues.pop()=="BugFix") {
    counter++;
  }
  if (counter>0) {
    var deletionRange = ss.getRange(rowAValues.length+2, 1, counter+1, 1); //Gets the range with lines that need to be deleted.
    deletionRange.clear();
  }
}
```

What it does is:

1. Gets the [non-blank values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) from the sheets
2. Filter these values to the column we want to analyze
3. Counts how many cells it needs to delete from the bottom:

   1. [`Pop`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the last value and compares it with "BugFix"
   2. If this is true, add a number to a counter.
   3. When this stops being true, halt the counting. (Hence the `while` loop instead of a `for`)
4. Get the `Range` with the correct coordinates (to clear multiple columns based on this data, just extend the Range to have the right columns
5. [`Clear`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear) it.

## Dealing with multiple conditions

### First Option: For Loop

You can change the `while` loop for a `for` loop that performs the same type of function:

> ```
>   var counter = 0;
>   while (rowAValues.pop()=="BugFix") {
>     counter++;
>   }
> ```

Becomes:

```
  var counter;
  var rowValue;
  for(counter=0,rowValue=rowAValues.pop(); rowValue=="BugFix" ||  rowValue=="SomethingElse"; counter++) {}
```

### Second Option: Another function

To keep your main function clear of the conditionals and allow for an easier extension, you can also delegate the filtering to another function.

Create a new function like this:

```
function filterValue(rowValue) {
  return rowValue=="BugFix" ||  rowValue=="SomethingElse";
}
```

Then change:

> ```
>   while (rowAValues.pop()=="BugFix") {
> ```

To:

```
  while (filterValue(rowAValues.pop())) {
```

Comment: and if I would like to add one more condition to check in the last row, i.e. if the last row is 'BugFix' or 'something_else', how to add it?

Comment: thank you, everything works - I used the second solution is simpler

Answer (score 0):

The first one is just like your example it just clears the last row

```
function clearLogs(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('logs');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn());//Third parameter is the number of rows not the last row
  var data = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();//I assumed the same condition 
  if (lastRow=='BugFix') {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();//This clears the entire row    
  }
}
```

This one deletes all the rows with "BugFix" in the first column:

```
function clearLogs1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var data=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  data.forEach(function(r,i){if(r[0]=='BugFix'){sh.deleteRow(i+2-d++);}});
}
```